# Getting SessionId inside Script tag - Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

JS on vf page  gets data from custom object and post on page,after making some changes on page when command button save presses nothing happens. when i took out sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}"; browser gives an error saying invalid session id and did not get any data for query, still page is displayed, when i press save it will call my methods. Iam not sure why sforce.connection.sessionID not making submit to work, Please help me.

Comment: can you share entire page code? Also, any specific reason you want to query via javascript, instead of querying in apex?

Comment: Iam getting all the soql data and creating a dynamic picklist, the picklist values will vary based on the data record types. purpose is to avoid governer limits.

Comment: did you tried to use javascript remoting? It can be a very fast and modular way to access such data.

Comment: Nope i didnot try JS remoting.  what could e the reason command button does not work with APISeSSIon variable?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered getting session Id like this:

```
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
var oResult = sforce.connection.query(query); 
var oDocuments = oResult.getArray('records'); 
</script>
```

Comment: No i did this <script type="text/javascript" src="/soap/ajax/24.0/connection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">    Does it Matters???

Comment: That does not matter but this does -"var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';". Try this once.

Comment: Not giving the fault Stirng, but same issue Command Link(save) is not working Any other suggestions?

Comment: Anyone any input, why command button not working with '{!GETSESSIONID()}';